# Is there are way to use Fine Grain Auditing to record Varray bind values?

Tags: oracle, spatial, array, audit

I have an application, and would like to use Oracle's FGA (Fine Grained-Auditing) to record varray bind information.  Specifically, I am using Oracle Spatial and need to know at what extent users are actually querying the data.  By default, the only value that is recorded by Oracle for varrays appears to be -1.

```
begin
dbms_FGA.add_policy (
object_schema => 'GDB',
object_name => 'COUNTRY',
policy_name => 'COUNTRY_Aud',
handler_schema => NULL,
handler_module => NULL,
enable => TRUE,
statement_types => 'SELECT' );
end;
/
```

The SQL_TEXT and SQL_BIND values that are returned are:

```
SELECT SHAPE FROM  GDB.COUNTRY WHERE mdsys.sdo_filter(GDB.COUNTRYS.SHAPE, 
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(:gtype1,:srid1,NULL,:elem_info1,:ordinates1), 'querytype=window') =         
'TRUE' #1(4):2003 #2(4):4326 #3(-1): #4(-1):
```

I know that I could create a procedure to handle the auditing, but I don't know how to retrieve the actual varray.

---

I have tried getting the values out of the DBA_HIST_SQLBIND view, but the varray values are always null.

```
declare
    test mdsys.sdo_elem_info_array;
    anytest sys.anydata;
    rc pls_integer;
begin
    select VALUE_ANYDATA into anytest from DBA_HIST_SQLBIND where SQL_ID='9vu11pguf5gx9' and datatype = 123 and rownum = 1;

    if(anytest is not null) then
        rc := anytest.getcollection(test);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Got it');
    else
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Null value');
    end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: The documentation says "for an array, the values recorded are only the last set of bind values"

Comment: @Phil, is that when you bind an array to a single row or when you bind an array to a statement for multiple execution?  For example, what I have above vs `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE bulk_collect_test SET object_id = object_id WHERE  object_id = :1' USING l_tab(i);`

Comment: Could you try selecting v$sql_monitor.binds_xml from v$sql_monitor while someone is running it? sql_monitor doesn't capture every sql but when it does, it usually has pretty good capture of binds. Varrays are  type struct, so we don't know how internally oracle will represent them. dba_hist_sqlbind is not useful since not all executions have their binds captured (it is by design). You might want to log a SR with oracle support and maybe they can help you.